# Reason for PyDev class-file-creation strangeness?

Tags: python, pydev

When I use PyDev to create a new class file, it creates my constructor with an error I have to correct:

```
class MyClass(Exception):
    '''
    classdocs
    '''

    def __init__(selfparams):
        '''
        Constructor
        '''
```

The editor complains:

```
Method '__init__ - Weaponry.NotLoadedException' should have self as first parameter
```

If I change `selfparams` to `self`, the error goes away. Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I would say that it is a bug as it is not following accepted practice - why not raise a bug report!

Comment: Would you happen to know where to file such a bug report?

Comment: https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/ looks to be the place to start or https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/pydev-code.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that PyDev has a number of templates that it uses for this. I would suggest that you check to see if the template for creating a class file has been edited and changed from the default.